# Properly handle Screen/Device Orientation

Tags: android, html, ionic-framework, orientation, screen-orientation

I have this example: http://codepen.io/poliveira89/pen/VeZLJX/

One this example, I have a `<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>` where I insert a Tab View with 2 tabs (Home and About) with nested views and nested states, as well.

My main focus: retrieve screen/device orientation and dynamically rearrange content for Portrait and Landscape orientation.

On the Home tab is what I "pretend" to achieve => update View (HTML) regarding the Models changes after a screen rotation. Which clearly does not work on emulator and real device.

I duplicated the example on About tab, because on Home tab does not work, but I have changed the code a little bit I have tried some "refresh" trigger with a button (ng-click) and $timeout with an alert. And when I click the button the View refresh the HTML with the new values on Model.

Note: I have tried with other triggers - `$http`, `$interval`, ...

I thought that could be something related to "cache" on the NavView, like this:

```
.state('tabs.home', {
  url: "/home",
  cache: false,
  views: {
    'home-tab': {
      templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
      controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

But, after I disable it, nothing have changed and still does not work.

PS: Screen Rotation/Orientation listener works, on emulator and real device, I have debugged on console messages.

What could be not working properly on Angular or Ionic? Or why only updates the View after the triggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're updating the $scope outside of the Angular digest loop.

Try:

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.orientation = $window.orientation;
});
```